# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'eval'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I keep getting that error: "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'eval'", could someone tell me how to fix it & what it means? here is my code btw:

```
from rply.token import BaseBox


class Loop(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, number, statementlist):
        self.number = number
        self.statementlist = statementlist

    def eval(self):
        for i in range(self.number):
            self.statementlist.eval()
    @staticmethod
    def gettokentype():
        return 'statement'


class While(BaseBox):
    def __init__(self, condition, statementlist):
        self.condition = condition
        self.statementlist = statementlist

    def eval(self):
        while bool(self.condition.eval()):
            self.statementlist.eval()

    @staticmethod
    def gettokentype():
        return 'statement'
```

whole error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
    parser.parse(tokens)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rply/parser.py", line 49, in parse
    current_state = self._reduce_production(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rply/parser.py", line 80, in _reduce_production
    value = p.func(targ)
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/parser.py", line 44, in program
    return p[0].eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Statements.py", line 27, in eval
    i.eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Loops.py", line 25, in eval
    self.statementlist.eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Statements.py", line 27, in eval
    i.eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Conditions.py", line 11, in eval
    self.statementlist.eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Statements.py", line 27, in eval
    i.eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Statements.py", line 9, in eval
    self.exp.eval()
  File "/home/runner/RealMotionlessLivedistro/Core/AST/Functions.py", line 55, in eval
    self.value = self.value.eval()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'eval'
```

any help is highly appreciated, so please xD

Comment: Please insert the error message as such and insert rply module

Comment: The error message is telling you that in line 55 - of code you don't show - `self.value` is a string (str) and str doesn't have a method `eval()`. Whatever sets `self.value` needs investigating, or perhaps that line should read `self.value = eval(self.value)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the python built-in functions [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval), its usage is different.

```py
>>> x = 1
>>> eval('x+1')
2
```